# Evaluating an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, block, evaluate

I'm trying to evaluate each position in an array and assign a new value to that position if it falls within a certain range. Here is my method code and method call:

```
def array_eval array
    array.each do |x|
        if x.to_i <= 10
            array[x] = 1
        else
            array[x] = 2
        end
    end
end

array_eval temp_array
puts temp_array
```

And here is my output error from the terminal:

```
carwashalgorithm.rb:109:in `[]=': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)

from carwashalgorithm.rb:109:in `block in array_eval'
from carwashalgorithm.rb:107:in `each'
from carwashalgorithm.rb:107:in `array_eval'
from carwashalgorithm.rb:117:in `<main>'
```

I can do this with control flow, but I know there is an easier way to evaluate all of these values using a block. This is what I'm trying to do with the above. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `each` loop calls the given block for each element, passing that element:

```
array.each do |x| # <- x is a reference to an element
  # ...
end
```

Inside the loop you call [`Array#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) with that element:

```
  array[x] = 1    # <- the same x
```

This doesn't work (it raises the `TypeError`), you have to pass the element's *index*.

You could use [`Array#each_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) - it passes the *index* instead of the element itself:

```
def array_eval(array)
  array.each_index do |x|
    if array[x].to_i <= 10
      array[x] = 1
    else
      array[x] = 2
    end
  end
end
```

Or [`Array#map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) - it replaces the element with the value returned by the block:

```
def array_eval(array)
  array.map! do |item|
    if item <= 10
      1
    else
      2
    end
  end
end
```

The above can be written as a one-liner (see [jethroo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527502/evaluating-an-array-in-ruby/19527654#19527654)):

```
def array_eval(array)
  array.map! { |item| item <= 10 ? 1 : 2 }
end
```

Comment: Great answer Stefan - thanks a lot.  First time I've seen that map method.  Also, thanks for linking source, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line in ruby:

```
array.map{|x| x.to_i <= 10 ? 1 : 2}

1.9.3-p194 :003 > a = [*0..20]
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] 
1.9.3-p194 :004 > a.map{|x| x <= 10 ? 1 : 2}
=> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: `nil.to_i` returns `0`, it doesn't raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: Wow, that's some powerful stuff, I have never seen this method - thanks for the answer, I'll be trying this out!

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the error is because the temp_array hasn't been instantiated (I don't see the creation of temp_array in your code example). If, however, the problem is like @jethroo states above, and you have a nil value in your array, you can add a check for nil on each element before evaluating .to_i on it:

```
array.map{|x| 
  if x.nil?
    puts 'element is nil, moving on...'
  else
    x.to_i <= 10 ? 1 : 2
}
```

Comment: Good point, I did instantiate the array, however, you would not have known from what I included above.  Thanks!